# How can I compare two equations in Mathematica , to check whether they are mathematically same or not?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Let's say expr1= Sin x
expr2 = e^x -e^-x/2j

Now we know they are the same mathematically, how will I come to know expr1=expr2 and they are the same?

Let's say I have these two equations and have code as these

```
FullSimplify[
  (ComplexExpand[#1, 
     TargetFunctions -> 
      {Re, Im}] & )[
   Abs[1 + (I*2*Pi)/
       (E^((-I)*2*Pi) - 
        E^((-I)*2*Pi*\[Lambda]))]^2]]
```

and then we have

```
(ComplexExpand[#1, 
    TargetFunctions -> 
     {Re, Im}] & )[
  Abs[1 + (I*2*Pi)/
      (E^((-I)*2*Pi) - 
       E^((-I)*2*Pi*\[Lambda]))]^2]
```

Both of them yield different answers but can I check whether they are the same or not?

Comment: Did you already try `FullSimplify[expr1 == expr2]`? (Incorporate variable assumptions with `Assuming[]` whenever applicable.)

Comment: FullSimplify[expr1 == expr2] I did it now, but this gave expr-2's answer? How would I come to know both answers of expr1 == expr2 @J.M.

Comment: You can also use `Reduce[expr1 == expr2]` to check the constraints for which equality holds. For example `Reduce[Sqrt[x^2] == Abs[x]]`.

Comment: Let's say expr1= Sin x 
expr2 = e^x -e^-x/2j

Now we know they are same mathematically, how will I come to know expr1=expr2 and they are same? @SjoerdSmit

Comment: Using your simpler example: `FullSimplify[Sin[x] == (Exp[I x] - Exp[-I x])/(2 I)]`. The `True` result implies that the equation is indeed true for all *complex* values of `x`.

Comment: Thank you, let's say we give names to these equations

ennui= Sin[x]
goodomen = (Exp[I x] - Exp[-I x])/(2 I)

and now we FullSimplify[ennui  == goodomen]

It yeild no such thing as true? WHY? You have an idea?@J.M.'sennui

Comment: One other simple way is to simplify the difference between these two expressions. If they are identical, the simplification will return zero.

Comment: @good_omen92 It gives `True` for me. Maybe try restarting your kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases it is easier to show the difference is zero.

```
expr1 = FullSimplify[(ComplexExpand[#1, 
   TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &)[
  Abs[1 + (I*2*Pi)/(E^((-I)*2*Pi) - E^((-I)*2*Pi*\[Lambda]))]^2]];

expr2 = (ComplexExpand[#1, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &)[
  Abs[1 + (I*2*Pi)/(E^((-I)*2*Pi) - E^((-I)*2*Pi*\[Lambda]))]^2];

expr1 - expr2 // Together // Simplify

(*   0   *)
```

Comment: I divide two-equations manually and solved the same equation by Mathematica, and let's say both are correct, FullSimplify[expr1 == expr2] yields a true? – Does that makes sense? @Akku

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to get a definitive answer to whether two expression are equivalent. It is an [undecidable problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_problem).

To let Mathematica do its best to find out, use [`PossibleZeroQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PossibleZeroQ.html) on their difference.

You can also use `FullSimplify[expr1 == expr2, assumptions]` which (a bit more usefully) can give `True` or `False` (meaning a certain result), or return the input (meaning "I don't know").

Comment: I was going to suggest `PossibleZeroQ`. Another thing to try is `FindInstance[...!=0]` to see if zero-equality can be disproved by counterexample.

Comment: I divide two-equations manually and solved the same equation by Mathematica, and let's say both are correct, FullSimplify[expr1 == expr2] yields a true?